# Are there any good Pascal Script resources/documentation?

Tags: delphi, scripting, pascalscript

I started playing around with Pascal Script today and I cannot find any good documentation.  I found these ([one](http://devcenter.remobjects.com/articles/?id=%7B2FFC1EE9-F18D-4B11-9DE4-1BA0A79D0D04%7D), [two](http://devcenter.remobjects.com/articles/?id=%7BB2CAB2FE-A831-452E-AF7A-6E2C6021D489%7D)) articles.  The are helpful but they are just examples.

**edit**: Separated this into two questions.  New question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743643/how-can-i-get-pascal-script-to-recognize-the-create-and-free-functions-when-i).

Comment: When you say you can't get it to recognize them, what do you mean?  What are you trying to do and what error messages are you getting from PS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to add some documentation of my own.  Its not very thorough but it should help out anyone who is new to Pascal Script.

Heres the [link](http://lawrencebarsanti.wordpress.com/2009/11/28/introduction-to-pascal-script).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this will help but last week, I started working with FastScript.  The first kinds of errors I ran into were the same as what you are seeing.  After studying the slightly helpful documentation and the much more helpful code, I saw that I needed to add a constructor for a class by using an AddConstructor call and any other methods of a class with a call to AddMethod.  I'm getting a better idea of just how their parsing works and it looks like I can assemble a reference to an arbitrarily complex class just by mirroring it with a series of calls to AddMethod, AddProperty, AddIndexProperty and so on.  Just like in Pascal, you start first by defining the simpler class and then use that simpler class in your more complex class.

Thinking about it over the weekend, it seems like this is one very practical way to build a scripter.  It could be that PascalScript has the same arrangement although undoubtedly, the names will be different.

Comment: Thanks.  This helped solve my problem.  In Pascal Script the methods are called RegisterMethod, RegisterConstructor, etc...  Also, Pascal Script comes with a tool called Unit Importer that builds the register code for you.  Unfortunately, it does not add the Create and Free methods so I just added them myself.  Lastly, I voted up this answer but if you repost it under the new question I'll accept it.

Comment: Larry,
I see you already accepted another answer that's probably more on point.  That's fine.  Thanks for taking the time to come back and share what you found.

Answer (score 1):

Some of us are using PascalScript here but docs are a little thin. You can take a look at the source of Innosetup (the installer) since this uses an editor and script engine from PascalScript to provide its own pascal scripting.
Brian

Answer (score 1):

The samples folder that comes with PascalScript is very useful, and performs reasonably well as a form of applied documentation.