# Delphi Applications in RemObject Pascal Scripter

Tags: delphi, pascalscript, remobjects

I want to run a Delphi application(With forms vcl, forms, etc) using another application with RemObject Pascal Scripter.

will RemObject Pascal Scripter support all the areas of delphi ,

If so can i include 3rd party VCL

If not what can you recommend me to build interpretable applications with forms and controls

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> will RemObject Pascal Scripter support all the areas of Delphi

Clearly **NO**. Haven't used it in a while but *"all the areas of delphi"* is asking allot. Embarcadero itself isn't setting the bar that high with the "Delphi for Mac". Kylix didn't aim for 100% compatibility either.

> can i include 3rd party VCL

Any class can be made available to the scripting engine. But the class itself resides on the compiled Delphi side of things, not on the scripted side.

> what can you recommend me to build interpretable applications with forms and controls

Take a look at the "mission statement" for the engine:

*"Pascal Script is a widely-used set of components for Delphi that makes it easy to add Pascal-based scripting support to your applications, so that they can extend or control your application with custom scripts"*

The author's not positioning it as an scripting engine for application development, but as an engine for extending the functionality of applications. None the less you can probably do a lot with it, it all depends on how you define "interpretable application".

Answer (score 2):

Well, yes and no.

**Yes** in the sense that you can *expose* pretty much every aspect of your application to the scripting engine.

**No** in the sense that *"all aspects of Delphi"* is too vague a definition to begin with.

I think that what you want is to control, through scripting, some third party control in your form. That is pretty much doable and it can be achieved by using the *Unit Importer* tool.

Now, there is not much documentation but you can get some useful advice in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743367/are-there-any-good-pascal-script-resources-documentation).