# Can I create installer that copies files from a UNC path on the network?

Tags: file, installation, copy, inno-setup, unc

Is it possible to create the Inno Setup script to copy files from a UNC path on the network rather than statically adding them to the setup file?

If so, can it still be done if I need to authenticate to the path first? Is there a mechanism to provide authentication info in the Inno Setup script?

Essentially, I am wanting setup to just copy files from various sources over the intranet from a UNC path to put into the setup destination directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, specify the UNC path in the `Source` parameter of the [`[Files]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection) entry and use the [`external` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=external).

```
[Files]
Source: \\UNC\path\file.txt; DestDir: {app}; Flags: external
```

---

To authenticate, you would have to call the [`WNetUseConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetuseconnectionw) or similar WinAPI.

See [How to execute "net use" command from Inno Setup installer on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13025271/850848)

Comment: Great! Thanks. Sounds like exactly what I was looking for.