# Inno Setup Pascal Script documentation

Tags: api, inno-setup

I started to use Inno Setup as I thought the Pascal Scripting would make it a lot easier for me to do custom stuff, compared to NSIS. However, it seems that there is no documentation anywhere on the Web? The [official Wiki](http://wiki.remobjects.com/wiki/Using_RemObjects_Pascal_Script) has been deleted and I can't find any API documentation. There was an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743367/are-there-any-good-pascal-script-resources-documentation) (3 years-old, an eternity!) which ended in the sad statement that nothing existed.

So far I was able to get help (mostly on Stackoverflow ;-)) each time I wanted to do something specific but I don't want to go accross forums each time I want to do something. My problem right now is to create a directory if it doesn't exist, and I haven't find anyone asking this question yet. So I'm asking. If you know how to do it, can you please tell me (how to do it ;-)) and **where** you learnt it?

Thanks!

Comment: In fact, you have two questions here!

Comment: Yes I know. Though the main question was about locating the documentation, you can consider the second one as the "application exercise" ;-)
¡Muchas gracias para tu respuestas! :)

Comment: @Mattieu no hay de qué, hombre, es un gusto, me alegra ser de alguna ayuda ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pascal script syntax is very close to the Pascal/Delphi syntax, so you have a lot of documentation in the [Delphi DocWiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE/en/Getting_Started_with_RAD_Studio) and [Free pascal documentation](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/ref.html) about it.

The best place I know about inno-setup specific pascal script function support is the PascalScript section in the Inno Setup Help File, the most relevant sections are:

- [Support Functions Reference](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptfunctions.htm)
- [Support Class Reference](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptclasses.htm)
- [Using DLLs](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptdll.htm)

As for your last question, take a look at this:

```
var
  DocPath: string;
  DirPath: string;
begin
  DocPath := ExpandConstant('{userdocs}');
  DirPath := DocPath + '\ISTest';
  if not DirExists(DirPath) then
  begin
    if not CreateDir(DirPath) then
       MsgBox(SysErrorMessage(DLLGetLastError), mbError, mb_Ok);
  end;
end;
```

Where I learned it? I'm a Delphi developer, and the aim of pascal script is to be close to Delphi, so I think I really learned it by learning Delphi. Nowadays, before to take a look at the documentation, I try to do what I want to do *a la Delphi*, and if I fail doing so, I resort to documentation as a last resource.

Comment: The links above are the primary reference, but also I wrote a semi-tutorial on Pascal as used in Inno [here](http://www.mirality.co.nz/inno/tips.php).

Comment: I knew about the `DirectoryExists()` function in Delphi that's why I get confused when I see that Pascal Script uses `DirExists()`...
Anyway, thank you for the insights about Delphi, I started programming with Pascal some 25 years ago, I guess I have to get back to it now ;-)

Comment: @Miral, thanks for the tutorial, it seems nice about the overview of the language syntax. I would have loved to see some kind of full API published somewhere online, like Java's JDK or MSDN for C#. At least, as @ jachguate mentionned, it seems strongly linked to Delphi so using the well-documented Delphi API as a base sounds good enough to me.

Comment: @Matthieu, the inno setup specific full API is documented, I linked that documentation in the answer. Did you visited the links?

Comment: @jachguate, yes I did, thanks again for pointing out. I realize I haven't been reading through the "Support Function reference", where there actually *is* a link to `DirExists` and `CreateDir`. I guess sleeping correctly is a key to a better understanding ;-)